# Yeoman/Yo: Where does Yo scaffolding pickup the name of the Angular module?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I created my Angular application using a specific module name and now I have decided to change it.

so when I do

```
yo angular:controller myController
```

it creates

```
angular.module('MyTestModule')
```

Where is `Yo` looking to pick this up, anyway of updating it ??

Thanks

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help. After a little bit of investigation it appears that the name is taken from the `component.json`, editing this file means that feature scaffolding will take the new name.

Comment: Just checked. The correct answer is "name" property in bower.json. You should consider changing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

In the current version (Yeoman 1.0.4, generator-angular 0.4.0) the name seems to be taken from the `"name"` property in the file `bower.json`.

Comment: Holymoly thank you so much! I have no idea why folder-find did not work in Sublime Text to spot this!

Comment: Also note that it will transform the name like this:

`"test" -> "testApp",
 "testForm" -> "testFormApp",
 "test-form" -> "testFormApp"`

Its IMHO not that obvious.

Comment: Notice that in the same file `bower.json` you also have the `moduleName` property. I changed them both.

Answer (score 1):

There's an extra "l" in "controlller myController" in your description above, which will default to causing yeoman (or yo) to create an entire angular deployment, not just the controller alone.  In any case its picking up part of that name from the directory of your deployment.   So for an example I did this:

```
mkdir yotest
cd yotest
npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower generator-angular
yo angular:controller myController
vi app/scripts/controllers/myController.js
```

And notice the name of my controller module:

```
...
angular.module('yotestApp') 
...
```

Comment: yes, that was a typo, sorry. Ah Ok.. So its only the directory. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure.  I actually find it a tiny bit annoying that it uses the directory name because sometimes that name changes for me in various deployment strategies, but given that yo is supposed to be pretty automated, going with general best practices & all, it still has high gain to loss ratio :)

Comment: Hi Hoonto, actually just did some tests and its not the directory, you have to edit the name in component.json

Comment: Ah component.json - that's much better, thank YOU Martin!  I think in SO if you found the answer to your own question, you can provide it and then accept it, correct?  I had actually decided to use yeoman to initially build out my structure on an app a few months ago, then just took over grunt myself because I was annoyed with that aspect (well also needed more control over a couple other things).  But I think that's a good-to-know thing that others may like to know as well.

Comment: My guess will be that bower.json gets its "name" property from the root directory, but once bower.json is in place, you can edit it, and have your scaffolding reflect those changes.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience (I dont use bower and then systematically delete all files about it), Yo pickup the name of the main module from the main folder.

And about the 'App' suffix, according to this commit https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/commit/09f0f7b3a8c3264b7527bc9fed8c709becec99eb, it can be modified using `--app-suffix="foobar"` when running `yo angular` commands :

```
yo angular foobar --app-suffix=""
yo angular:controller myCtrl --app-suffix=""
```

will create :

- A module named `foobar`
- A controller : `foobar.myCtrl`

But I don't know how to save set this option as default behavior. I do not think it is possible.