# Where to change the name of app?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I installed the `generator-angular`, but decided to change the name of my app midway. Now when I generate any module it gets the wrong name attached to it. I tried Find+Replace of both myOldApp and my-old-app but I still get the old name. Where do I change it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Yeoman/Yo: Where does Yo scaffolding pickup the name of the Angular module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168131/yeoman-yo-where-does-yo-scaffolding-pickup-the-name-of-the-angular-module)

suggests it is in the bower.json.

worked for me.

Comment: I forgot I created this question :) Yes, I found that answer a few minutes after writing this...

Comment: Do note that it will always add the suffix 'App', so if you enter 'test' as app name in the bower.json config file and then generate a controller, it will be named testApp.<controllername>

Answer (score 0):

go to your `app ->open bower.json->` there will be a `name` field change it there

Answer (score 0):

We changed it in our package.json.  It'll remove the generator-

```
{
  "name": "generator-foobar"
}
```